# How to automate Apple App Store analytics?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm trying to automate pulling analytics from the Apple App Store. I'm mainly trying to get monthly downloads filtered by device. This is easy to do through App Store Connect, but I'd like to do it programmatically. I tried using the API, but it doesn't appear to support pulling analytics. I can get the sales and trends report from the API, but this is for a free app, so there are no sales. I found what someone claims is an internal API at `https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/analytics/api/v1/data/time-series`, but it doesn't have any documentation and I haven't been able to make it work. Has anyone found a simple way to just get downloads?

Update:
That internal API works, but it requires a browser cookie called "dqsid." I am able to get that cookie, but it expires after 30 minutes, which kind of defeats the purpose of automating this. If anyone knows of a way to log in to the App Store Connect programmatically and pull the cookie, that would be helpful, though I think I would run into problems with multi-factor authentication.